# Why does the last symbol in the string double after 'std::remove'?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I wanted to delete one symbol ':' from the string.

```
std::cout << str << " "; //1948: 59 63
std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ':');
std::cout << str << " ";//1948 59 633
```

In case when I change the range to [str.negin(), str.begin()+5) everything is ok.

Comment: Google for "erase-remove idiom".

Comment: Or, for better hits, "remove-erase idiom" =P

Answer (score 3):

`std::remove` does not remove elements from a range. Removing elements using iterators is not possible. However, it moves all the elements that you *don't* want to remove to the beginning, and then returns an iterator pointing to the end of those items.

The correct way to use `std::remove` is like this:

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ':'), str.end());
```

It will move all the "good" elements to the front (`std::remove` does that) and then it will erase the remaining ones (`str.erase` does that).

Answer (score 1):

You have to erase the redundant symbol (or symbols).

For example

```
str.erase( std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ':'), str.enc() );
```

The algorithm `std::remove` moves specified elements that should be removed) to the end of the used container. More precisely it moves actual elements to the beginning of the container taking the places of the removed elements.

Comment: Есть орфографическая ошибка.  `enc`